# WPF C# WebView doesn't show any page on win 10

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, webview

If have tried to test the sample project from Windows community but couldn't get any page running on my machine.

I got those events in event viewer:

> Faulting application name: Win32WebViewHost.exe, version:
>   10.0.17134.1, time stamp: 0xed1839dd
>  Faulting module name: edgemanager.dll, version: 11.0.17134.165, time stamp: 0x71de0339
>   Exception code: 0xc0000409
>  Fault offset: 0x0000000000035694 Faulting process id: 0x2ca4
>  Faulting application start time:
>   0x01d433adb58e4f8b
>  Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_cw5n1h2txyewy\Win32WebViewHost.exe Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\edgemanager.dll
>   Report Id: 40986bf3-66d8-4018-9f7e-81c8b65e42b6
>  Faulting package
>   full name:
>   Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.17134.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Faulting package-relative application ID: Win32WebViewHost

AND:

> Faulting application name: wwahost.exe, version: 10.0.17134.165, time
>   stamp: 0xc46b1662
>  Faulting module name: wwahost.exe, version:
>   10.0.17134.165, time stamp: 0xc46b1662
>  Exception code: 0xc0000409
>  Fault offset: 0x000000000005744c
>  Faulting
>   process id: 0x3330
>  Faulting application start time:
>   0x01d433bcbf627fdd
>  Faulting application path:
>   C:\Windows\System32\wwahost.exe
>  Faulting module path:
>   C:\Windows\System32\wwahost.exe
>  Report Id:
>   7ebdd067-07b4-4278-a566-531fb78506ac
>  Faulting package full
>   name:
>   Microsoft.Win32WebViewHost_10.0.17134.1_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy Faulting package-relative application ID: Win32WebViewHost

Ive tried to:

1. repair VS 2017
2. installed all .net target versie tot 4.7.2
3. installed all .net versies tot 4.7.2 in win
4. did sfc /scannow
5. did window repair

[Sample.zip](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsCommunityToolkit/files/2160583/WebViewSample.zip)

Sample Code :

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebViewSample"
    xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.WPF;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls" x:Class="WebViewSample.MainWindow"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <WPF:WebView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="webView1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="10,10,10,9.5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" x:Name="textBlock1" ></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        webView1.DOMContentLoaded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            textBlock1.Text = "Loaded!";
        };

        webView1.Navigate("https://microsoft.com");
    }
}
```

Extra info :

- Win 10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.165)
- Test on several machines with random results

Comment: Hi, can you post relevant code here instead of posting a zip file?

Comment: There is nothing more than the code above...

Comment: What version/build of Windows 10 are you on?

Comment: Win 10 Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.165)

Comment: `edgemanager.dll` is not something trivial (I don't have this on a Windows Server 2016 machine). Do you have another machine with different OS to test?

Comment: Did test on 6 maschine and there was random situations/results... I had done research on known issues on Webview site and came to conclusion that is not working in several situations and that it is no solution/option for us on this time... I will wait for further releases...

Comment: Can you try on a newer Windows Insider build? There are some cases where the control may fail due to an activation issue with CoreUI and/or Edgemanager that have been fixed. You can download from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windowsinsiderpreviewadvanced

Answer (score 1):

WebView does not support running under an elevated token.
see: https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/32#issuecomment-442447380

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` doesn't seem to work properly when calling `Navigate()` from view constructor. [Issue 3286](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/issues/3286).

Try moving your `Navigate()` call to the `Loaded` event.

```cs
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    webView.Navigate("https://microsoft.com");
}
```