# WPF WebView doesn't show

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, webview, wpftoolkit

I'm learning WPF WebView control, I have the below `MainWindow.xaml` file:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPF"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">
        <WPF:WebView x:Name="webView1"
                      Grid.Row="0"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      Loaded="WebView_Loaded" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and the below corresponding `MainWindow.xaml.cs` file:

```
namespace MyWPF
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
        }

        private void WebView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

But I don't get any expecting popup window. If I remove

> webView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));

I can get a blank popup window. What is wrong with my code and how to solve it?

**UPDATE1**

I added `Window_Loaded` event handler and move the below two in it, now I can see a blank popup window but without any content as well as message box.

```
Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
WebView1.Navigate(uri);
```

The whole updated code-behind:

```
namespace MyWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
            WebView1.Navigate(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE2**

I added one HyperLink and one Button into xaml file, the below is the updated xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPF"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="False" >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1" Visibility="Visible" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="71*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WPF:WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,50,50,50">
        </WPF:WebView>
        <Button Name="BTN1" Click="BTN1_Click" Margin="285,380,285,10" Grid.Column="1" >Click Me</Button>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,747,390" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Hyperlink
                NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">
                Google
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and adding Button click event handler into the code-behind with webview initialization inside it:

```
namespace MyWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");

            //Uri uri = ;
            WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
        }
        private void BTN1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
            WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing happens after clicking the HyperLink. I see popup Messagebox after clicking button but still google doesn't show up.

**UPDATE3**

I followed the link:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview#high-dpi

I set Source property `Source="http://www.google.com"` inside the xaml file, see the below code:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyWPF"
        xmlns:WPF="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" AllowsTransparency="False" >
    <Grid x:Name="Grid1"  >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="71*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <WPF:WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,50,50,50" Source="http://www.google.com" >
        </WPF:WebView>
        <Button Name="BTN1" Click="BTN1_Click" Margin="285,380,285,10" Grid.Column="1" >Click Me</Button>
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,747,390" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
            <Hyperlink
                NavigateUri="http://www.google.com">
                Google
            </Hyperlink>
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

But still not working.

**UPDATE4**

I added`((ISupportInitialize)webView).BeginInit()` and `((ISupportInitialize)webView).EndInit()` into the button click event handler, see the below:

```
using Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace MyWPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
        }
        private void BTN1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Loaded");
            ((ISupportInitialize)WebView1).BeginInit();
            ((ISupportInitialize)WebView1).EndInit();
            WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://localhost:3000"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

But get the below error message at this line:
            `((ISupportInitialize)WebView1).BeginInit();`
:

> - $exception  {"Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture.  Make sure
>     \"Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.UI.Controls.DesignerUI.resources\" was
>     correctly embedded or linked into assembly
>     \"Microsoft.Toolkit.Wpf.UI.Controls.WebView\" at compile time, or that
>     all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully
>     signed."} System.Resources.MissingManifestResourceException

Then I went back and added more properties based on this link:

> https://github.com/rjmurillo/webview-samples/blob/master/Toolkit/dotnet/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.Samples.WPF.WebView/MainWindow.xaml

```
<WPF:WebView x:Name="WebView1" Visibility="Visible" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50,50,50,50" Source="http://www.google.com" IsIndexedDBEnabled="True"
            IsJavaScriptEnabled="True"
            IsPrivateNetworkClientServerCapabilityEnabled="True"
            IsScriptNotifyAllowed="True" >
</WPF:WebView>
```

But still WebView not working.

Comment: What you think is wrong with your code ? i'm not sure what you expect to happen when you remove that line of code.

Comment: No expectation, but wondering why without that line, I can see popup window.

Comment: Is `WebView` obligatory? With `WebBrowser`it does work.

Comment: Yes, WebView is a must, I found WebBrowser working as well.

Comment: You should call `webView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://www.google.com"));` when Window is loaded, not in constructor.

Comment: @fhnaseer still not working, check out the update.

Comment: Have you checked [Known Issues of the WebView control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wpf-winforms/webview-known-issues)? Does it work, if you set a link in XAML?

Comment: @Rekshino I set a link but still not working, please check new updates.

Comment: Actually I have found it only neccesary for second `WebView` and I doubt it helps, but may be can also help you: `((ISupportInitialize)webView).BeginInit()` and `((ISupportInitialize)webView).EndInit()`

Comment: Try also to set additional attributes, may be it's just a permision or a browser/`WebView` setting. See [example](https://github.com/rjmurillo/webview-samples/blob/master/Toolkit/dotnet/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32.Samples.WPF.WebView/MainWindow.xaml)

Comment: @Rekshino Still not working, please check out the update.

Comment: See also [WPF C# WebView doesn't show any page on win 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51854862/wpf-c-sharp-webview-doesnt-show-any-page-on-win-10) Try run your app as administrator.

Comment: i tried same but getting below error on WPF control in xaml ny ideas?.."The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "UIElement"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same issue upgrading from the first preview Toolkit, and it was all because the `Navigate` function causing to start window hidden.

Change from:

```cs
WebView1.Navigate(new Uri("https://localhost:3000"));
```

To:

```cs
WebView1.Source = new Uri("https://localhost:3000");
```

Comment: Actually, it helped to see the app window but the WebView ctrl still does not show the website...

Comment: I had issue with WebView in WPF as well but once i specified Height and Width in XAML it showed up.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having this issue and even using the

```
myWebBrowser.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com");
```

it was not showing the page.

I added the following to the code and now it loads fine.

```
 myWebBrowser.BringIntoView();
```

I am using this with WPF and displaying it in a popup window, I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the issue I was having or not.

Answer (score 1):

Did you run your program as an administrator (with elevated privileges), either directly or through Visual Studio?

According to this [discussion](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/Microsoft.Toolkit.Win32/issues/32#issuecomment-442447380) this is not possible, the Win32 WebView does not support running under an elevated token.

If you check your Windows event log, you should also find an application error like the one mentioned in the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

I also tried to use WebView WPF, but it can not show when I use `webview.Source = url` as accepted answer.

Finally, I changed to use CefSharp.Wpf library following this link https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/using-the-cefsharp-chromium-web-browser-in-wpf-xaml/

And it worked perfectly at my site, i shared for whom concerned.

Create a new WPF project

Obtain the `CefSharp` packages using NuGet

Select Tool > NuGet Package manager > Package Manager Console.

Use the PM> `install-package CefSharp.Wpf`

Use in WPF as

```
<Window x:Class="CefSharpBrowser.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="350" Width="525">
     
    <Grid>
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser
            x:Name="Browser"
            Address="http://www.myaddress.com" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```